# How to show alternative directions in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have collected data of specific restricted zones in Google Maps. Now I want that when a user opens my app for getting directions for a Point B from Point A, he should be shown an alternative direction which does not include the restricted zones which I have mentioned.

How should I proceed?
What steps should I follow such that those restricted zones get ignored while showing alternative directions from Point A to Point B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get alternative direction, you can use the [Google Maps Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Introduction) which is a service that calculates directions between locations using an HTTP request.

You can use the [optional parameters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters) alternative to provide one or more alternative route.

`alternatives` — If set to true, specifies that the Directions service may provide more than one route alternative in the response. Note that providing route alternatives may increase the response time from the server.

Comment: Thanks, But how to set avoid = something that I have created, like a specific road on which I have selected some roadblocks?